# How to exclude a maven test scope from package phase?

Tags: java, maven

I'm collecting all dependency libraries in a separator folder on `mvn package` as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.copy.plugin}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Problem: this also include `<scope>test</scope>` libraries.
How can I exclude these libs?

Comment: First question: Why are doing this? What is the intention of doing a thing like this? Creating a EAR/WAR/ ?

Comment: Didn't you read the manual? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope

Comment: @khmarbaise my goal is to create a runnable jar without all libraries packed inside, but in a separate folder inside the execution dir. Reduces file size when the project itself is updated, but no dependencies changed (have to copy the jar project often over the net).

Comment: You could use the maven-assembly-plugin with an appropriate descriptor for this. but i would recommend to create a sepearate zip file which contains all that (bin folder with a script; lib folder with the jar's and maybe an etc folder with some kind of configuration). This can be done by using appassembler-maven-plugin...

Comment: go for ant in this case. maven is not about this.

Comment: Well but if I can achieve this simple by maven (and it works already!), why should I go for another configuration tool?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use an [`includeScope`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#includeScope) to include only `runtime` scoped dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.copy.plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Apparently, `<excludeScope>test</excludeScope>` does not seem to be supported because the `test` scope covers all dependencies (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-85).

Comment: I tried it, but got following error: `Can't exclude Test scope, this will exclude everything. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Hm, I found this is probably not possible: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-85

Comment: Right, you can use the workaround mentioned in the issue comments: mainly include only runtime scope dependencies.